# How to get the input value from $(this).context

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, fullcalendar, contextmenu

My Full calender external events are displayed as following

```
<?php foreach ($plants as $plant) { ?>
      <div class='fc-event evt'>
           <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $plant->hcpd_id;?>" class="abc">
           <p class="evt_name"><?php echo $plant->hcpd_name;?></p>
      </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And this is my jquery

```
$('#external-events2 .fc-event').each(function() {

  var str = $(this).context;

  $(this).data('event', {
    title: $.trim($(this).text()),
    stick: true, 
    color : '#4AC948',
    className : "sub",
    id : //need to add the id here
  });


});
```

I want to give a specific id to each event. (taken from the database. It is given in the hidden input field)

Following is one of the generated divs.
I want to get the hidden id of the following $(this).context result

```
<div class="fc-event evt ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" class="abc">
    <p class="evt_name">My Plant 1</p>
</div>
```

Any idea of how to retrieve that.
I tried string replacing, but didn't work.

Comment: Where is your jQuery for `$(this).context` ? Please display all **relevant** source code.

Comment: You'll likely need `$(this).find('input.abc').val()`, but it's hard to say without seeing *where* you're getting `this` from.

Comment: "Hidden ID"?  What's that?

Comment: @isherwood: His `<input type="hidden" value="1" class="abc">` elements.

Comment: I see no source for an ID on those elements.

Comment: If you're using `$(this).context` why not use `this.id` because **this** is the same element.

Comment: ok I have edited my code here..

Comment: Replace `var str = $(this).context;` isn't being used in anything and to get the `id` use `this.id` but your elements **must** have an id to get.

Comment: Why use input in the first place and not use a data attribute? For that matter why aren't you providing events data to plugin using json?

Comment: @gecco are you getting confused with a **`value`** and **`id`** because both a different things. ID = identifier / Value = a value of something.

Comment: @NewToJS seems you are the one confusing id... php is passing `value`

Comment: Thanx everyone for the quick support :) Saved ma day.. :)

Comment: @gecco correct me if i'm wrong but your question is **How to get the input ID** right? The input ID <-- no mention of php value. The input id is the id="this" assigned to the input element also "I want to give a **specific id to each even**" Could you be more clear with questions in future please.

Comment: @NewToJs No. I want to pass a id. So I am using input hidden tag value attribute to store the data I want and fetch it later.

Comment: @NewToJs ok Sorry for my mistake. Somehow I got the answer thanx to you all

Comment: @NewToJs Ok I have changed the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What event are you using? For example, if you are using the click event:

```
$('.fc-event').click(function(){
    //Get the ID
    var eventID = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val();

    //Do whatever you want with the ID here.

});
```

Comment: Doesn't this just get the value of the element and not the `id`?

Comment: Thanx for the help.. I tried $(this).find('input.def').val() and it worked.

Comment: @NewToJS Since the ID is the value as defined in PHP, technically, yes, both.